# Download and get the original filename with htmlunit?

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I want to create a little application that download and install/upgrade all my windows software.
But there are more and more annoying javascript systems.

I tried phantomjs, but it can't download.
I just tried htmlunit and it works very well to download or getting original filename.
I can not get it to do both at the same time. My code doesn't work.

```
package com.example.simpledownloader;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        testDownload();
    }

    public static void testDownload() throws IOException {

        // Turn htmlunit warnings off.
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);

        // Init web client and navigate to the first page.
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_31);
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.videohelp.com/software/AV-Splitter");

        // Get the anchor element.
        String xpath1 = "//*[@id=\"Main\"]/div/div/div[11]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a[6]";
        HtmlElement element = (HtmlElement) page1.getByXPath(xpath1).get(0);

        // Extract the original filename from the filepath.
        String filepath = element.click().getUrl().getFile();
        String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filepath);
        System.out.println(filename);

        // Download the file.
        InputStream inputStream = element.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        // Close the webclient.
        webClient.close();
    }
}
```

Getting filename works but the downloading doesn't.

I've got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\htmlunit46883917986334906.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

It's maybe because I already clicked to get the filename?

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question is. Do you want to get the filename _and_ download using HtmlUnit ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I don't know why my actual code doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at your code, you have a section `// Extract the original filename from the filepath.` which I presume gets the filename, and a section `// Download the file.` Can you clarify what does not work here ?

Comment: The two operate separately. But once assembled as in my code, it does not work.

Comment: Do you see anything in the output ? Does it print the filename ? Do you get anything in the output file (what ?). I tried your code, it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are clicking twice.

How about:

```
// Extract the original filename from the filepath.
Page page2 = element.click();
String filepath = page2.getUrl().getFile();
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filepath);
System.out.println(filename);

// Download the file.
InputStream inputStream = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
int read;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with HtmlPage but not with Page. ;)